# Breaking up a input list, into several columns

Tags: powershell

How can I input a list, and have the contents display in multiple columns, say after three items; example:

```
$carlist = "c:\temp\list-of-cars.txt"             # listing 10 cars               
$num-cols = 4
```

Content would be:

```
Car1          
Car2
..       
Car9      
Car10

$c = $carlist.count/$num-cols                     # some number of columns  
write-host $carlist (something)
```

Output would be (based on the number of columns:

```
Car1          Car4          Car7          Car10                                             
Car2          Car5          Car8                           
Car3          Car6          Car9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cars = get-content "list-of-cars.txt"
$cars | Format-Wide {$_} -Column 4 -Force
```

Or, if you prefer the one-liner:

```
Get-Content .\list-of-cars.txt | Format-Wide {$_} -Column 4 -Force
```

Comment: All good responses... I should have included that I have "ForEach" statement, which does each "car", and the result of that, I'm trying to format into columns.

Comment: @user1821848 If you could give some more detail in your question, and include your code, then I can update my solution to be more in line with what you had in mind.

Comment: # create input window...
#
# code for input window, with listing everything...
#

$carlist = "list-of-cars.txt"
$numcols = 4

ForEach ($car in Gc $carlist) { 
 code for creating button labeled $car
 button.click opens window
 some other things...
 }

# code takes list of cars, 
# creates buttons for each $car, 
# and creates $numcols columns to display input window.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `Format-Wide` cmdlet:

```
Get-Content cars.txt | Select-Object @{n='name';e={$_}} | Format-Wide -Column 4
```

Comment: This one liner also worked, and great for listed results.  My objective was to do something, and have the results in columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

```
Function SplitTo-Column($colnum, [object[]]$list)
{
  for($i=1; $i -le $list.Length; $i++)
  {    
    if ( ($i % $colnum)  -eq 0) 
    {
       [Console]::WriteLine($list[$i-1]) #or write-host "$($list[$i-1])" is more posh    
    }
    elseif ($i -eq $list.count)
    {
       [Console]::WriteLine($list[$i-1]) #or write-host "$($list[$i-1])"
    }
    else
    {
       [Console]::Write($list[$i-1] + "`t" ) #or write-host "$($list[$i-1])`t" -NoNewline  
    }
  }
}
```

use:

```
$carlist = gc c:\temp\list-of-cars.txt             # listing 10 cars               
$numcols = 4

SplitTo-Column -colnum $numcols -list $carlist
```

Comment: This one did work for me...  The only output was the value of $carlist.

Comment: @user1821848 I think you mean didn't work! I forgot a `get-content` in `$carlist` value assignement...

Comment: Christian, I was testing what you answered, and my question is more detailed as such: with another example, if I was to say ping a list of servers, how could I display the output of all server not in a list, but in a display of 4 columns?  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who appreciates Linux utilities I've wanted to do a Powershell version of `expand` for a while. It converts tabs to spaces and offsets the spaces by the length of the preceding string.

My solution is a two-parter. The first part, `Expand-Tab` is my interpretation of `expand` in Powershell. It takes an array of strings and does tab expansion on them, but can take other delimiters. The second part, `Format-Columns`, takes an array of strings or string cast-able items to construct a tab separated list limited by the number of columns desired. Then it calls `Expand-Tab` to set the columns.

It looks like this

```
$Example = @(
    "one", "two", "three"
    "four", "five", "six"
    "seven", "eight", "nine"
)

$Example | Format-Columns  -Columns 3 -Spacing 20

Output:
one                 two                 three               
four                five                six                 
seven               eight               nine
```

It doesn't auto-size so it does rely on you having an idea of how long your strings will be but it's more tweak-able than `Format-Wide` if you want a limited number of columns that don't span the entire screen (2 columns on an ultra-wide monitor would look dumb). Also, it can take a list of strings without having to convert it to a Psobject first which is unintuitive behavior.

Hopefully doesn't contain any bugs XD

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Converts tabs to spaces.

.DESCRIPTION
    Converts tabs to spaces. Takes into account
    the length of the string when calculating the
    tab stop so the number of spaces will vary
    depending on the string given.
    
    Additional tabs will be added when a string
    exceeds the configured tab stop.

.NOTES
    Inspired by the Linux utility "expand"

.EXAMPLE
    Expand an array of strings

    ("one", "two", "three") -join "`t" | Expand-Tab

.EXAMPLE
    Expand an array of strings using a different delimiter
    and longer tab stop.

    ("one", "two", "three") -join "|" | Expand-Tab 20 -Delimiter "|"

#>
function Expand-Tab {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias('expand')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]] $InputObject,

        # Position=0 because we assume pipeline usage by default
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [uint32] $TabStop = 8,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Delimiter = "`t"
    )

    begin {
        $Builder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
    }

    process {        
        foreach ($String in $InputObject) {
            $Segments = $String.Split($Delimiter)
            $Counter = 0
            foreach ($Segment in $Segments) {
                $StringTabLengthRatio = $Segment.Length / $TabStop

                # Accomodate strings that are empty or equal to the tabstop by
                # adding an additional 1. For others, round up so the final 
                # tabstop exceeds the string size.
                $TabStopMultiplier =
                    if ($StringTabLengthRatio -eq 1 -or
                        $StringTabLengthRatio -eq 0)
                    {
                        $StringTabLengthRatio + 1
                    }
                    else {
                        [Math]::Ceiling($StringTabLengthRatio)
                    }


                $CalculatedTabStop = $TabStop * $TabStopMultiplier
                $SpacesRequired = $CalculatedTabStop - $Segment.Length
                [void] $Builder.Append($Segment)

                # Avoid adding a trailing tab on the last item.
                $Counter += 1
                if ($Counter -lt $Segments.Count) { 
                    [void] $Builder.Append(" ", $SpacesRequired)
                }
            }
            $Builder.ToString()
            [void] $Builder.Clear()
        }
    }
}


<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Formats an array of strings or objects that can
    cast to string in columns

.NOTES
    Format-Wide isn't configurable enough and
    takes up too much space.

.EXAMPLE

$Example = @(
    "one", "two", "three"
    "four", "five", "six"
    "seven", "eight", "nine"
)

$Example | Format-Columns  -Columns 3 -Spacing 20
#>
function Format-Columns {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(  
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]] $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [uint32] $Columns = 3,

        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [uint32] $Spacing = 8,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Property
    )

    begin {
        $LineBuffer = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
        $ColumnCounter = 0
    }

    process {
        foreach ($Item in $InputObject) {
            [string] $Segment = if ($Property) { $Item.$Property } else { $Item }

            # Flush buffer
            if ($ColumnCounter -eq $Columns) {
                $LineBuffer.ToString() | Expand-Tab $Spacing
                [void] $LineBuffer.Clear()
                $ColumnCounter = 0
            }

            if($ColumnCounter -eq 3) {
                [void] $LineBuffer.Append($Segment)
            } else {
                [void] $LineBuffer.Append($Segment).Append("`t")
            }
            $ColumnCounter += 1
        }
    }

    end {
        # Flush anything left over
        if ($LineBuffer.Length -gt 0) {
            $LineBuffer.ToString() | Expand-Tab $Spacing
            [void] $LineBuffer.Clear()
        }
    }
}
```